# OPTIMIZING QUERY - ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-performance

I have a query fetching information from a large database. Fetching one customer records takes minimum 12 seconds. I have estimated doing through the whole table will require not less than 12 days. Have a look at a it and help if it can be optimized

```
   SELECT gam.CIF_ID
        , TO_CHAR(T1.TRAN_DATE, 'MM') AS MONTH
        , SUM(TBAADM.COMMONPACKAGE.getConvertedAmount('TZ', tran_amt, tran_crncy_code, 'TZS', 'REV', tran_date)) AS TOTAL_DEBIT_AMT
        , ROUND(AVG(TBAADM.COMMONPACKAGE.getConvertedAmount('TZ', tran_amt, tran_crncy_code, 'TZS', 'REV', tran_date)), 3) AS AVG_DEBIT_AMT
        , COUNT(T1.PART_TRAN_TYPE) AS NUMBER_OF_DEBIT_TRANSACTIONS
     FROM TBAADM.HIST_TRAN_DTL_TABLE     T1
LEFT JOIN TBAADM.GENERAL_ACCT_MAST_TABLE gam  ON ( gam.ACID = T1.ACID )
    WHERE T1.PART_TRAN_TYPE = 'D'
      AND NOT EXISTS ( 
                    SELECT 1
                      FROM TBAADM.HIST_TRAN_DTL_TABLE     T3
                INNER JOIN TBAADM.GENERAL_ACCT_MAST_TABLE g    ON ( g.ACID = T3.ACID )
                     WHERE T3.PART_TRAN_TYPE ='C'
                      AND T3.TRAN_DATE || T3.TRAN_ID=T1.TRAN_DATE || T1.TRAN_ID
                      AND g.cif_id = gam.cif_id 
          )
      AND (
                T1.TRAN_SUB_TYPE='CI'
             OR T1.TRAN_SUB_TYPE='SI'
             OR T1.TRAN_SUB_TYPE='PI'
             OR T1.TRAN_SUB_TYPE='RI'
          )
      AND gam.ACCT_OWNERSHIP <> 'O'
      AND T1.TRAN_SUB_TYPE   <> 'CP'
      AND gam.SCHM_TYPE      <> 'LAA'
      AND tran_particular LIKE 'POS PURCHASE        %'
      AND T1.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN '1/JAN/14' AND '30/JUNE/18'
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(T1.TRAN_DATE, 'MM')
        , gam.CIF_ID
        ;
```

Comment: Sorry but without data, indexes, execution plans, and just with one query, it’s impossible to help

Comment: You need to provide more information than just the query like table structure, index details and what you are trying to retrieve etc

Comment: Are those `tbaadm.commonpackage` functions declared as `deterministic`? (And are they deterministic?)

Comment: `'1/JAN/14'` is not a date literal (though you might get away with the default implicit conversion). That should be `date '2014-01-01'`.

Comment: Observe the hint of Jaime Drq ! In any case I'd start with replacing the disjunctions in your where clause ( `... AND T1.TRAN_SUB_TYPE IN ('CI', 'SI', 'PI', 'RI')` instead of `AND ( T1.TRAN_SUB_TYPE='CI' OR T1.TRAN_SUB_TYPE='SI' OR T1.TRAN_SUB_TYPE='PI' OR T1.TRAN_SUB_TYPE='RI' )`). You may also drop the redundant `AND T1.TRAN_SUB_TYPE   <> 'CP'`.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on with `and t3.tran_date || t3.tran_id = t1.tran_date || t1.tran_id`. Why not two separate conditions?

Comment: So your date range suggests you're trying to search **4.5 years' worth of records**. How many records is that? What percentage of all the records in the table is that? How long do you think it should take?

Comment: It's a wild guess without any additional inof, but I'd suspect the calls to `getConvertedAmount` and `to_char(t1.tran_date, 'MM')` to force the query engine into a full table scan (basically a row-by-row inspection and processing - very expensive). Guesswork continued (wrt column semantics): It might be a good idea to augment your data model (ie. a new column for the transaction amount in your reference currency and for the month of the transaction date.

Comment: Hey, without knowing your indexes, then it will be hard to see where this can be optimized. Since you are searching a Transaction History table, my guess is that it may not be indexed at all, and that is why you are having such low performance. This is especially true since you are essentially full table scanning it twice in this query. I have experience doing something similar to what you are doing. Adding an index to the table may be too costly in both time and memory. I would suggest adapting your query into a stored procedure and processing hist_tran in chunks using an id column.

Comment: What's the execution plan?

Comment: In the SQL Monitor report, where is the time being spent and on what operation?